# Holomorphic automorphisms of analytifications of proper varieties

Tags: complex-geometry, automorphism-groups

I have two questions of a similar nature:

- Is it true that any holomorphic automorphism of an analytification of a proper variety over $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraic?
- If the first is not the case, is there a reference for projective varieties? I understand this should follow from GAGA, but I am unsure what an exact reference should be.

Comment: This is true, and follows from Proposition 15 in Serre's GAGA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an easy observation that a holomorphic map between algebraic varieties is algebraic if and only if its graph is algebraic. Therefore any map between proper algebraic varieties is algebraic (apply GAGA to the graph, which is a subvariety of the product). For projective varieties GAGA is overkill and Chow's lemma is sufficient.